# How to get HttpServletRequest / Response within a JSP tag?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm creating a custom jsp tag in the following way:

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FooTag extends SimpleTagSupport
{

    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException
     {
        JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
        out.println( "some response"  );
    }

}
```

My question is, is there a way for me to access the `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` in the `doTag()` method? If its not available from within java, can I pass it as a parameter from the jsp somehow? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are extending the `SimpleTagSupport`, you can call the inherited method `getJspContext()` which will return a `JspContext` object (which will give you access to page, request and session objects), cast it to a `PageContext`:

```
PageContext context = (PageContext) getJspContext();
```

Then simply retrieve the `ServletRequest` from the `context` object:

```
ServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest();
```

Comment: will this work for servlet response too?

Comment: Yes for sure, take a look at the [PageContext class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) .